# Below is an XSD file. I was wondering if there is a way to have another element "PreviousYear" which is "CurrentYear - 1"

Tags: xsd

Here is an XSD file where I want to add an element PreviousYear which is CurrentYear-1

```
<xsd:complexType name="ConstantsType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="CurrentYear" type="xsd:string" fixed="2013" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have fixed the value of CurrentYear at 2013 by using a string literal, there doesn't seem to be any reason not to define

```
<xsd:element name="PreviousYear" type="xsd:string" fixed="2012"/>
```

When you change one, you will need to change both.

This does not, however, look like a particularly convenient design:  on January 1, the name CurrentYear will become misleading unless you revise the fixed values in the schema; if you do revise the fixed values, all your existing valid documents containing CurrentYear elements will become invalid.  (Also, it seems perverse to type CurrentYear as xsd:string when it's clearly intended to have the meaning of an xsd:gYear.)

It's possible, of course, that you just need to define some basic information like this for use in programs of one kind or another; in that case, an element saying that the current year is 2013 might make sense.  The only problem I am having with this idea is that I can't think of any situation where such information might be useful that doesn't involve a programming language, and I can't think of any programming language that doesn't already have access to a better way of finding out what year it is at run time.

Comment: Sperberg-McQueer thanks for the input. You see I am new to this and I was trying out few things and I came across this scenario. Thanks for the great input. It helps.